# Return a nested list of child table using Kotlin Exposed Dao

Tags: kotlin, dao, kotlin-exposed

I have a parent table of stores and items it sells. I then have a child table with units sold for each item across the stores. I would like to have an exposed `DAO entity` which gives me the item and store details from the parent table and the units sold for each item as a nested list from child table.

I understand that `referrersOn` and `referencedOn` can be used, however in the documentations [StarWars](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO) example, the child table needs to have a column indicating the parent_id row it is joined to. This does not work in my case as my child table can be associated to multiple parent_ids.

How can I update the below code so the parent entity class returns me the nested list of units sold, using the `item` column as the link between the two tables?

### Parent Table

| parent_id | Store Name | Region | Item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Store1 | Texas | ItemA |
| 2 | Store2 | Nevada | ItemB |
| 3 | Store3 | Florida | ItemA |
| 4 | Store4 | Nevada | ItemB |
| 5 | Store5 | Arizona | ItemA |

```kotlin
// Table A definition
object TableA : IntIdTable() {
    val storeName = varchar("store_name", 50).uniqueIndex()
    val region = varchar("region", 50)
    val item = varchar("item", 50)
}

// Entity class for Table A
class TableAEntity(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<TableAEntity>(TableA)

    var storeName by TableA.storeName
    var region by TableA.region
    var item by TableA.item
}
```

### Child Table

| child_id | Item | Date | Units sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ItemA | 2023-05-20 | 10 |
| 2 | ItemA | 2023-05-21 | 15 |
| 3 | ItemA | 2023-05-22 | 8 |
| 4 | ItemB | 2023-05-20 | 5 |
| 5 | ItemB | 2023-05-21 | 12 |
| 6 | ItemB | 2023-05-22 | 6 |

```kotlin
// Table B definition
object TableB : IntIdTable() {
    val item = reference("item", TableA)
    val date = date("date")
    val unitsSold = integer("units_sold")
}

// Entity class for Table B
class TableBEntity(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<TableBEntity>(TableB)

    var item by TableB.item
    var date by TableB.date
    var unitsSold by TableB.unitsSold
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you need a many-to-many reference.

Create an intermediate table for storing references:

```
object TableATableB : Table() {
    val tableA = reference("tableA", TableA)
    val tableB = reference("tableB", TableB)
    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(tableA, tableB)
}
```

Add a reference to TableA

```
// Table A definition
// Entity class for Table A
class TableAEntity(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<TableAEntity>(TableA)

    var storeName by TableA.storeName
    var region by TableA.region
    var item by TableA.item
    var tableB by TableBEntity via TableATableB
}
```

(I would use tablenames that reflect the contents)

See https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO#many-to-many-reference